# Wikipedia API request sometimes not returning results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, wikipedia

I want to make a request to the Wikipedia API to see if a given name has a Wikipedia page.

For example, let's say I make an API request to get the page for Justin Bieber:

```
    source = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=justin%20bieber&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"
    data = open(source).read
    json = JSON.parse(data)
```

Then I get back a JSON response with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=justin%20bieber&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json) info. But why is it not returning any result for some less well known name (even though they have wiki pages?) For example, this brent bolthouse page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent_Bolthouse. If I check [the json](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=brent%20bolthouse&format=json), there's no indication that it's an actual page..

I basically just want to implement a simple check to see if there's a wiki page that matches the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capitalizing all parts of the name, e.g.:

```
"brent bolthouse".titleize
=> "Brent Bolthouse"
```

I suggest this because the titles of Wikipedia's pages on persons always have that format. While your URL with the lowercase name as the query doesn't work, the URL with the capitalized name [does](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Brent+Bolthouse&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found out MediaWiki is case sensitive for page titles.